# Horizontally transition on Fancybox 2

Tags: fancybox

I need a help with Fancybox 2 about the images transition. The script is creating the transitions vertically, and I would like that the transitions were from right to left, like most of lightbox scripts found on the web. I only found a explanation but it was not "right-to-left" but "left-to-right".

Does anybody have a tip or solution for this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the `.js`, look for these 3 strings

```
(g.top=n(parseInt(g.top,10)-200),i.top="+=200px")
```

and

```
f.top="+=200px"
```

**What was done**

this was the changes I've done to achieve a horizontal transition.

for the first string,

```
(g.top=n(parseInt(g.top,0)-0),i.left="+=0px")
```

and for the 2nd string,

```
f.left="+=200px"
```

hope this helps!